# Both the old and the new bike[s?]

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Say I have one old and one new bike.

Should I write:

> Both the old and the new bike should be there.

or

> Both the old and the new bike**s** should be there.

Comment: I'd say the noun phrase in ***both** [adj1] **and** [adj2] [np]* can be either singular OR plural. Hence [*Strive to achieve a balance in both yours and their **lives**,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22balance+in+both+yours+and+their+lives%22) and [*Every word you say plants a seed in the 'garden' of both yours and their **life**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22of+both+yours+and+their+life%22) The only difference I see in your exact examples is that the singular implies there are only two bikes (one of each kind), but there *might* be several with the plural version.

Answer (score 1):

The first is more specific: you have one of each.

The second is less specific: you have a mixture of old and new bikes.

Answer (score 0):

> **Both the old bike and the new bike should be there**.

**The old bike** is singular

**The new book is singular**

So the old bike and the new bike are plural and mean one old book and one new book.

So the above sentence is correct.

If you say :

> **Both the old and the new bikes**, it means some old bikes and some new bikes.

It is not what you intended to say